# GLX context for creating OpenCL context

Tags: opengl, opencl

Question: How do I take a GLXContext and pass it to clCreateContextFromType?

---

Info:

I'm learning how the openGL CL interop works. I've managed learn how openCL works and how openGl works, now I'm on the final step of making them work together. I was using glut, but have since started using GLX because I need a GL context for CL to be able to create its context from. I have my GLXContext saved as a global variable and I pass it to to clCreateContextFromType and i get this when I compile:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘GLXContext {aka __GLXcontextRec*}’ to ‘cl_context_properties {aka long int}’
```

So i ran around the internet, found some advise from this [blog](http://oscarbg.blogspot.com/2009/10/about-opencl-opengl-interop.html), and made a cl_context_properties list which contained {CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, glc}. It threw the exact same error. What am I missing here? there obviously something that needs to happen in order to make this GLX context suitable for openCL to take. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
cl_context_properties props[] =
{
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentContext(),
    CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentDisplay(),
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platform_id),
    0
};
```

Why it works I don't really know. But I found it [here](http://enja.org/2010/08/27/adventures-in-opencl-part-2-particles-with-opengl/).

Comment: Well, this is a so called property list. Such kinds of lists are used to supply an arbitrary number of parameters to a function. The even numbered elements (0, 2, 4, ...) tell *what* is supplied with each following odd numbered parameter.

Comment: Since you found the answer youeself, please also accept it for marking the question as being resolved.

Comment: I still don't really get why I could cast it in the properties list but couldn't cast it in a different way. But thanks.